# Item added to list regardless of input

Tags: python

We are creating a text game for a class project and I have an issue with the defined statement below.
Logically, it seems right, but functionally, it is not working. The 'Item' is added to my list regardless of the input.

```
def show_item(current_location):
    room_item = ''
    if 'Item' in current_location:
        room_item = current_location['Item']
        print('You see a', room_item)
        pick_up = input('Would you like to pick up item?')
        if pick_up == 'Yes' or 'yes' and room_item not in current_items:
            current_items.append(room_item)
        elif pick_up != 'Yes' or 'yes':
            pass
        else:
            print('You currently have this item')
    else:
        print('Invalid Input')
    return room_item
```

This is the output below I receive:

```
Escape The Freeze
Collect 6 items to win the game, or be frozen alive!
Move commands: South, North, East, West or Exit 

Invalid Input
You are in the Gym
Your current items: 
Enter a command North
You see a meal
Would you like to pick up item?No
You are in the Teachers Lounge
Your current items: meal
Enter a command South
Invalid Input
You are in the Gym
Your current items: meal
Enter a command South
You see a gloves
Would you like to pick up item?woo woo
You are in the Office
Your current items: meal,gloves
Enter a command
```

Comment: `if pick_up == 'Yes' or 'yes'` and `elif pick_up != 'Yes' or 'yes'` make sense in English but computers require such tests to be written a bit differently. See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value) for explanations of why and what to write instead.

Comment: Made some changes and it is working closer to the intended design.